# correct mysql syntax for a column not equaling either of two values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table 'cars' with a column for colour. I'm trying to build a query which will show all cars which have 4 doors, but exclude all cars which have 'red' or 'black' recorded in their colour column.

```
SELECT * FROM 'cars'
WHERE 'cars.doors = 4'
AND 'cars.colour != red OR black'
```

This doesn't seem to work, but I'm not sure if its because I've got it all wrong whether there's something else in my code messing it up. Is this ok to do this way?

thanks

Comment: you have your other SQL syntax wrong as well. Please learn to tell one literal from another.

Answer (score 6):

You're enclosing the conditions in single quotes which is invalid. You should only enclose strings in quotes. For the not red or black part you can use `NOT IN()`

```
SELECT * FROM `cars`
WHERE cars.doors = 4
AND cars.colour NOT IN('red', 'black')
```

Alternatively you can do it the long way, note the use of `AND` not `OR` because `OR` wouldn't be appropriate for what you want.

```
AND cars.colour != 'red' AND cars.colour != 'black'
```

Comment: I think you should remove the quotes from `'cars'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NOT IN`,also quotes are incorrect use `backtics` ` for column & table name.

```
SELECT * FROM `cars`
WHERE `cars`.`doors` = 4
AND `cars`.`colour` NOT IN ('red','black')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell explicit, which fields have to be compared

```
SELECT * FROM `cars`
WHERE `cars`.´doors` = 4
AND `cars`.´colour` != 'red' AND `cars`.´colour` != 'black'
```

you have a problem with your quotes, too. i've corrected them

Comment: The precedence of AND compared to OR might give this unforeseen results.

Comment: thanks for the correction :) i missed that point (copy/paste)

Answer (score 2):

In your **where** condition you have placed `'cars.colour != red OR black'` as wrongly

And this should be like

```
SELECT * FROM cars
WHERE doors = 4
AND colour != red AND colour != black
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM cars
WHERE doors = 4
AND colour NOT IN('red', 'black')
```

Comment: Your two examples are not functionally equivalent. Should be using `AND` not `OR` in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `cars`
WHERE cars.doors = 4
AND cars.colour NOT IN ("red","black");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (cars.doors = 4) AND ( cars.colour NOT IN ("red","black"))
```

and, other solution :

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (cars.door = 4) AND (cars.colour <> "red") AND (cars.colour <> "black")
```